# Different methods to open a website

Tags: java, android, button, web

I want to implement a button in my app which leads to a website. I found these two easy ways to solve it and I wonder if there is actually a functional difference between these two methods?

1st way:

```
Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://google.com/");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    startActivity(intent);
}
});
```

2nd way:

```
Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.yourURL.com"));
    startActivity(intent);
}
});
```

Comment: Both are the same in all aspects if you clearly open your eyes and see. Just the arrangement of statements are different. That doesn't make it work any different functionally.

Comment: Thank you bozzmob :) I just started java a few weeks ago. I`m not quite 100% used to these different ways of arrangements. I will try to learn it.

Comment: No problem Niclas :) This is obviously a learning forum, let's learn. But, just do your homework before you ask questions here :) It will help a lot of people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Intent documentation (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html), the first and second parameters to the constructor merely set the Action and the Data URL (respectively).

So:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
```

Would be functionally identical to:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(uri);
```

The only difference I see would be the inclusion of the category in the second block, which is documented here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#addCategory%28java.lang.String%29